# Can a lookbehind be used in conjunction with a non-fixed length pattern?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am using regular expressions and attempting to match a pattern after excluding a previous pattern.

The regular expression I am using:

```regex
(?<![\(\d+\:\d+\)])\d+
```

The content the regular expression above is being applied to:

```
(0:1) Whenever someone moves,
 (1:0) and they are on map 5,
 (1:35) and they move into position (19, 22),
    (5:19) move the triggering player to (13, 7, 92).
```

I am attempting to match the following:

- 5
- 19, 22
- 13, 7, 92

I am trying to not match the following:

- (0:1)
- (1:0)
- (1:35)
- (5:19)

Comment: Try it like this `(?<=\(\d+\:\d+\).*)\d+` https://regex101.com/r/djvUq1/1 Or if the parenthesis part should occur at the beginning of the string `(?<=^[^\S\r\n]*\(\d+\:\d+\).*)\d+`

Comment: What regex flavor are you using? How about `(?<= )([\d, ()]+)[,.]$`, assuming the digits and parenthesis area is always at the end of line?

Comment: @ggorlen I am using C# and yes, the line always ends with a comma or period. As a user pointed out below, its regex engine supports variable width lookbehinds.

Answer (score 4):

You should remove the square brackets, or else it would denote a character class matching one of the listed characters.

Using the negative lookbehind will also match the digits in the first parts like `(0:1)` because the assertion is true for the position before matching the digits.

Instead you could use a positive lookbehind to assert that the pattern with the parenthesis is on the left and then match 1+ digits.

```
 (?<=\(\d+:\d+\).*)\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fEBXxx/1)

If the pattern should be present as the first thing from the start of the string:

```
(?<=^[^\S\r\n]*\(\d+:\d+\).*)\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZZ3NK4/1)

Answer (score 2):

Not really, not unless you are using C#, whose regex engine supports variable width lookbehinds.  Instead, the typically way you would approach this would be to iterate over your input line by line and then use the following regex pattern:

```
^\s*\(\d+:\d+\).*?(?:(\d+)|\((\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*)\)).*$
```

### Demo

Comment: Note: not only C# regular expressions support variable width lookbehinds. Vim does, too. Python `regex`, latest JavaScript RegExp engine, Visual Studio Code, too.

Comment: @RyszardCzech Not true at all.  For example, using a variable width lookbehind in Python yields the error `look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`, with a similar error in JS.

Comment: At all? `print( regex.findall(r'(?<=ABC.*?)\d+', 'DEF 123 ABC 23 45 67 MAN') )` [returns](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gqugKDOvRAPC0UvLzEtJzMnRKFLXsLexdXRy1tOy14xJ0VbXUVB3cXVTMDQyVgCKKgApE1MFM3MFX0c/dU0Fzf//AQ) `['23', '45', '67']`